# lightning: open case in edit mode with defaulted record type from list button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I want to open case in edit mode with xyz record type from the case list view in lightning

```
/500/e?RecordType=01215006777xxx
```

not seems to be working. 
Is there any alternatives for this?

Comment: Have you tried [force:createRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_createRecord.htm) event?

Comment: from the list button i cant call the lightning component directly as URL only supported. Is there a way to do that without embedding in VF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have raised a case with salesforce and they confirmed that this is not possible now. So i created a VF page.